# plot two functions in deferent interval using Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I plot this function. Now I want change this code that plot the blue graph in center and cut this graph after the dash line and plot black curve out of the two dash line.I need to plot to tree parts.

```
  eqn[d_Integer?NonNegative, r_, B_, A_, nmax_Integer?Positive] 
  :=Sum[Exp[-n*\[Lambda]]*(1 - r)^n Exp[n*k^2 - k^2*A 
  (HarmonicNumber[n + d] - HarmonicNumber[d]) + 
   B*k*HarmonicNumber[n]], {n, 1, nmax}] == -1 +Exp[\[Lambda]]/r;
   AValues = {2};
   BValues = {1};
Show[Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},ContourPlot[Evaluate@
Table[eqn[0, 0.25, B, A, 100], {A, AValues}, {B, BValues}], {k, 
-2,2}, {\[Lambda], -0.5, 3.5}, 
FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {k, 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(r\)]\)(k)"}), 
  RotateLabel -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 GridLines -> {{-0.5, 1.0}, {0}}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, AbsoluteThickness[1], 
Dashed]]],Plot[k^2 + Log[0.75], {k, -2, 2}, PlotLegends -> 
Placed[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(0\)]\)(k)+ln(1-r)"}, 
\{.5, .7}], PlotStyle -> {Black}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you understand this and find my errors? `d=0; Show[Table[ListPlot[Table[{B,B*kcsq}/. FindRoot[Sum[Exp[-B*kcsq*(HarmonicNumber[n+d]-HarmonicNumber[d])],{n,1,320}]==(1-r)*Exp[kcsq]/r-1,{kcsq,1/2}],{B,0,1,1/10}],Joined->True],{r,{.25,.5,.75,.9}}]]` Fig 2 and Eqn 31 use `kc^2` so I use variable `kcsq` I make plots for each `r` For each plot I make 11 points `{B,B*kcsq}` I sum first 320 terms and solve for `kcsq` The graphs are very wrong. Can you see and explain any errors? I will try to understand and fix.

Comment: If I `FindRoot` for `kc` and then square that for the graphs then the result is the same.